# Moving git commits on public master to an existing branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, rebase

I have a git repo with public `master` and `develop` branches. I committed to `master` when I should have committed to `develop`. I understand that I can move the commits from `master` to `develop` with the following commands

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick 0123455678 # whatever the hash is I want to move
git checkout master
git rebase -i HEAD~2
git push -f
```

But this conflicts with what I understand about rebasing, specifically

> Do not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Other developers will have pulled both of these branches, so how can I make sure that they are up to date with the rewritten history?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably add the commits to the correct branch and then [revert](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) them in master. Revert just adds a new commit to master which undoes the previous wrong changes. It might look a bit messy in the history but it doesn't break anything for anyone who already has pulled those updates.

Comment: then I'd have two commits in `master` that needn't be there. I'd rather have a clean history in `master` and go through the pain of rewriting history and getting everybody synced up properly.

Comment: And have *everybody* go through the pain of having history rewritten.  You should really use @jcoder's solution.

Comment: @qntmfred what is your question then? Either rewrite your history and make sure everybody else moves to your rewritten history or don’t rewrite and do a revert. There are no other options.

Comment: ^^ "everybody" in my case means 5 people. My question is - everything I've read says "don't rewrite history because people will hate you" but if I'm willing to go through that in this case, do my 5 people have to do anything other than a normal `git pull` to get synced up with the rewritten history?